# Need to exclude folders, or POM relative path from Jacoco code coverage in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, jacoco

Hi tried to exclude folders from Jacoco code coverage in Azure Devops

[image: azure-pipeline.yaml looks like below]

i wanna exclude below paths

```
src/main/java/com/ing/investment/remoteadvice/*/model/**
src/main/java/com/ing/investment/remoteadvice/*/enums/**
```

also tried adding -: `com.ing.investment.remoteadvice.*.model.*`. but did not work

could someone help me on this

Comment: Hi ramesh, is there any update for this issue? The task doesn't support the behavior you want for now;, but you can post a feature request in [user voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to share your feedback if you do want this feature. BTW, please check if my workaround can make some help~

Answer (score 0):

> Need to exclude folders, or POM relative path from Jacoco code
> coverage in azure devops

As I know the Maven task doesn't support `path-filter` input. It only supports `class-filter` to include or exclude classes from collecting code coverage using `codeCoverageClassFilter` input.

You can check the inputs of the task [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet).

**Workaround:**

So assuming you have structure like:

```
src/main/java/com/ing/investment/remoteadvice/*/model/**
src/main/java/com/ing/investment/remoteadvice/*/enums/** 
src/main/java/com/ing/investment/remoteadvice/*/folderA/**
src/main/java/com/ing/investment/remoteadvice/*/folderB/**
```

We can't exclude `model` and `enums` folders, instead we can pass `src/main/java/com/ing/investment/remoteadvice/*/folderA/**,src/main/java/com/ing/investment/remoteadvice/*/folderB/**` to `codeCoverageClassFilesDirectories` input.

See description of `codeCoverageClassFilesDirectories`:

```
This field is required for a multi-module project. Specify a comma-separated list of relative paths from the Maven POM file to directories containing class files and archive files (JAR, WAR, etc.). Code coverage is reported for class files in these directories.

For example: target/classes,target/testClasses.
```